# How do I export a .glb with a single animation?

Tags: animation, export

I've been struggling with this for a while, whenever I export a model as a .glb, the rig and shape key animations are separated:

[image: A list of animations as displayed in 3D Viewer.]

Here you can see the armature animations playing without the shape keys:

[image: The armature animations, playing alone.]

Here you can see the shape key animations playing without the armature animations:

[image: The shape key animations, playing alone.]

And here's how the animation is supposed to look (ideally it wouldn't rotate when being exported as a .glb one can freely move):

[image: The animation, with both armature and shape key animations playing at the same time.]

How can I make Blender export these as a single animation, so that the shape keys play at the same time as the rig animations?

You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLMihatFMacEZXzRsNgUi5goJLffd48L/view?usp=sharing)! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I got it! All I had to do was uncheck "Group by NLA track" in the export menu.

[image: A view of the export menu with "Group by NLA track" unchecked.]

You can find more information [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#export).